# iPhone 4 - sound only comes out of one speaker

Tags: iphone

I have notices that sound only comes out of one speaker on the bottom of my phone. Is it playing in mono or is the other "speaker" actually a microphone?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The iPhone 4 only has one speaker. The matching screen on the other side of the phone is for the microphone.

[image]

Comment: This is also the case for the iPhone 2G, 3G and 3Gs.

Comment: iPhone 2G, 3G, 3GS are **almost** the same: on those, the speaker is left and the mic is right.

Comment: I've had an iPhone 4 for over three years and somehow never noticed this until just a few days ago. I thought I had damaged it somehow – that's a relief!