# iPhone 4S stereo sound

Tags: iphone, audio, sound-volume

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone 4 - sound only comes out of one speaker](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3926/iphone-4-sound-only-comes-out-of-one-speaker)

I finally got my iPhone 4S! But when playing a song, I noticed the sound isn't stereo. The right box is doing all the hard box, while the left one is producing a very minimal sound. Is this standard on the iPhone 4S or is it a hardware/software issue?

Comment: The sound is stereo out the headphone jack so use that jack to drive headphones or a set of stereo speakers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is expected - the iPhone 4S does not have stereo speakers. The left "box" is actually a microphone:

[image]

<sup>*image from [apple.com/iphone/specs.html](http://www.apple.com/iphone/specs.html)*</sup>

Comment: @Michiel it's not entirely stupid - I imagine a lot of new users are confused by it

Comment: Yeah; use headphones for stereo sound.

Comment: I'm used to work with an iPhone 3G with broken speakers, so... But thanks!

Comment: I like this implementation. If I need to shut up my iPhone, I just hold my thumb on that right hole. It's a really effective way to mute the phone.