# iPhone 4s only producing mono sound

Tags: audio, iphone, sound-volume

Related to: [iPhone 4S stereo sound](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/33861/iphone-4s-stereo-sound/35531#35531)

This is strange. I know people with the iPhone 4 (not the 4S as I have) who are getting audio from both "boxes". In addition, I don't get stereo with headphones either. I get stereo output but both L and R channels produce just R - meaning the R channel is outputting to both. What is this?

Comment: I doubt they are getting audio from both, as there would be no way to speak into the phone if that was the case. As you are getting just the R out put from your headphones, I'm not sure, maybe someone else can help?

Comment: Which sound sources have you tried?

Comment: The difference between this and the other post is that this iPhone does not output stereo with headphones either.

Comment: Have you tried with different headphones? Are you sure the song you're listening to is stereo? Also, your friends are lying to you. I've had iPhone 3G, 3GS, 4 and 4S, and only the right "box" is the speaker: the left, per the article you linked to, is the microphone.

Answer (score 5):

The fact that people say they are getting sound from both grills at the bottom of any iPhone is total nonsense, all models have a Microphone and a speaker at the bottom.

If Apple replaces the microphone with a speaker, the phone would be rendered useless as there would be no way of it picking up speech.

It is a very common misunderstanding.

A couple of things to check.

- Clean the headphone jack - any dust or fluff can cause the signal to break
- Go to -Settings>general>accessability>Mono audio make sure this is off
- Compare with a friend's phone, same model, same track, same head phones, then try new headphones, and after that a new song.
- if there is still a problem go to an Apple store.

Answer (score 1):

Put some alcohol on a Q . Tip and clean out the Earphone Jack it collects a lot of dirt & grime let dry a few minutes & plug earphones in should be fine